# How to make a responsive menu, which on width adjustment turns into a slide out menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I split my website into two parts.
**70%** of the left part is main content and on the other **30%** is a menu.

Link for preview: https://codepen.io/ficko90/pen/xxJLxxr

Full Code:

```css
#main-content {
  width: 70%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: green;
}

.tag-menu {
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  right: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 650px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.tag-menu-header {
  width: 400px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.tag-menu-header h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#post-count {
  color: #8d8888;
  float: right;
}


/* Tag Start */

.tag {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 2px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

.tag-dot {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.tag:hover {
  border: 3px solid;
}


/* width */

.tag-menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}


/* Track */

.tag-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: black;
}


/* Handle */

.tag-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgb(25, 23, 23);
}


/* Handle on hover */

.tag-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>asdas</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tag-menu-header">
    <h1>Your Tags</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="tag-menu">
    <table style="width: 100%; height: auto">
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="tag" style="border-color: red; color: red;"><span class="tag-dot" style="border-color: red; color: red;"></span>Math</span></a></td>
        <td>
          <p id="post-count">177 Posts</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="tag" style="border-color: blue; color: blue;"><span class="tag-dot" style="border-color: blue; color: blue;"></span>English</span></a></td>
        <td>
          <p id="post-count">25 Posts</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="tag" style="border-color: purple; color: purple;"><span class="tag-dot" style="border-color: purple; color: purple;"></span>German</span></a></td>
        <td>
          <p id="post-count">46 Posts</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="tag" style="border-color: orange; color: orange;"><span class="tag-dot" style="border-color: orange; color: orange;"></span>Notes</span></a></td>
        <td>
          <p id="post-count">9 Posts</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="main-content">
    <h1>Main Content</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Error: When the window resizes its width, the menu goes over the main content due to its `position: absolute`

As of my preference, I don't want to have a slide-out-menu, when the page is in a full sized window, because I want to fill out the empty space. Instead, when the menu is about to come close to the main content, I want it to turn into a slide out button, that can showcase a menu and gray out everything behind it.

I haven't found anything like my request, without the use of SCSS

For my project I use: Bootstrap, pure CSS and JavaScript.

I have no such knowledge to fulfill the task, so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
                                    .
```

Comment: Use media screen to handle your issue

Comment: I only know how to use media screen when it comes to placing the menu on top or under the main content, but not actually hiding it behind the button and then pulling it out

Comment: Listen use it and tell your button that hide its children when media screen approach your limmit.need help?

Comment: Code example would be a greater help for me to understand, how to hide elements on limit and then show them on click, which then greys out everything behind the menu

Comment: U know net speed here is a turtle kinf of. And can't see your code in that 'codepen' site but you know i will write you an example then if it didn't worked for youplz don't vote down.I'll give it my best shot

Comment: I never critized the help provided to me :)

Comment: If it inspired I'd be happy.if u need extera explanation I'm up here

Comment: Since you're using Bootstrap, why don't you use the [suggested sidebar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/sidebars/)? You can also make it [collapsible](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/collapse/), and trigger it on certain resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="circle-menu-button" tabIndex=0 onClick="openSideMenu()"></div>
 <div id="ready-to-show-by-click-on-circle-button" class="my-side-menu">
  <span>f line</span>
  <span>s line</span>
  <span>th line</span>
 </div>
 <div class="my-body-container">
 Foo
 </div>
```

Css

```
  /*mobiles*/


.my-body-container{
 Width: 100vw
}

.my-side-menu{
  display: none;
  Width: 300px
 }

.circle-menu-button{
  display: block
 }

/*pc or tablet*/
 Media-screen min-width 413px{

  .my-body-container{
   Width: 70vw
  }

 .my-side-menu{
  display: block;
  Width: 30vw
  }

 .circle-menu-button{
  With: 50px;
  Height: 50px;
  Border-radius: 50%;
  display: none;
  Background: lightblue;
  }

}
```

JS

```
function openSideMenu(){
document.getElementById('ready-to-show-by-click-on-circle- 
button').style.display='block'
 }
```

Comment: Seems like your solution blanks out the whole page and only shows "Foo" without any menu or button. Try to use the css code I put out and try to make it dissappear behind a button on certain windows size

Comment: On mobile side menu disapeared and by tapping on a button it shows up .and in windows size u have no button and just have side menu.isn't what u were looming for? I am not native in english.may be I got something different from wt u need

Comment: It has a button on top of screen on mobile.without side menu and then u tap the button and boom. On windows no button only side menu there is

Comment: your syntax is wrong and the solution doesn't work. At least the one your provided in your answer

Comment: Syntax are wrong ofcurse and didnt try to write it down correctly.just it is a inspirationif you wish I will correct them.itis because of using mobile.very limmited to code.just in a case of guide

Comment: If u want my code works correctly yoh should replace some lines and add some css in your design.take a look on media screen I just write.it is a sample of code.the correct one starts with @media...

Comment: @media screen and (min-width:413px){..}

Comment: thanks for inspiration, but I was looking for an answer without further puzzles trying to figure out.

Comment: Sorry I lost the net for a while.do you need clean code that just copy that?if yes I'll do it for you